# Why is *ngIf not updating when @Input decorated variable used in validation is changed?

Tags: angular

Let us say I have an HTML template:

```
<div *ngIf="data?.authentication?.validUser">
    <p>{{ data.authentication.validUser }}</p>
</div>
```

In the component TypeScript file:

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() data;
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.data); // Output: undefined
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.setAuthentication();
    }

    setAuthentication(): void {
        if (!this.data?.authentication) {
            this.data["authentication"] = { validUser: "Yep, valid!" };
        }
        console.log(this.data.authentication); // Output: { validUser: "Yep, valid!" }
    }
}
```

Initially, when the @Input data is undefined, the div and p tags are not being displayed. Understood!

But when data.authentication.validUser is set to `"Yep, valid!"`, why are the tags not being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, when a data is shared using `@Input()` directive, it is not available within your `constructor` that's why it is returning `undefined`.

To watch the changes happening, or may be set and perform some action as soon as the value is binded you can use the following two approach.

1. Using NgOnChanges

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() data;

    constructor() {
    }
    
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
       if (changes?.data?.currentValue) {
         console.log(this.data); // here you'll see the value
         this.data = changes?.data?.currentValue;
       }
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.setAuthentication();
    }

    setAuthentication(): void {
    }
}
```

2. Use Input Setters:

```
_data: any;
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    
    @Input() set data(value: boolean) {
       this._data = value;
    }

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.setAuthentication();
    }

    setAuthentication(): void {
    }
}
```